# Multiple data while displaying with where clause

Tags: php, jquery

guy's i want to ask. why when i try to displaying data from my database with where clause, the data that was showing has been multiple of that data? ( the condition while displaying when button click). but when i just call my php code. it running well, it just showing the data that i need to show
i use this code for showing data. i use jquery ajax call button function

```js
// JavaScript Document
$(document).on('click','#show',function(e) {
    var data = $("#form_input").serialize();

    $('#table_1 tbody').empty();
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: "Post",
            url: "../php/bkk/bkk_show.php",
            success: function(data){
  var list = JSON.parse(data);
  for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
                $('#mat').val((list[i]['material']));
                $('#lok').val((list[i]['lokasi']));
                $('#kpl').val((list[i]['kapal']));
                $('#po_numb').val((list[i]['po']));
                $('#date').val((list[i]['tanggal']));

                var tr = "<tr>";

                tr += "<td>" +list[i]['no']+"</td>";
                tr += "<td>" +list[i]['no_pol']+"</td>";
                tr += "<td>" +list[i]['netto']+"</td>";
                tr += "</tr>";
                $("#table_1 tbody").append(tr);
  }
  return false;
}
});
});
```

Comment: So when the data is coming from the database something goes wrong? Do you use multiple tables in your database query? Perhaps you haven't joined the tables properly.

Comment: multiple of the data as in duplication? ... Also post the result if possible.

Comment: @Hmmm yeah.. that data has a duplicate

Comment: @KIKOSoftware when i just running the php code. it working fine. but when i use button onclick with that code i post. it was duplicated data

Comment: add this in your click function, e.preventdefault() ... also Are you sure that php is returning correct data but the js function is duplicating it ?

Comment: @Hmmm im sure of it. i've try to run the php file only. and it work fine

Comment: Check the network to make sure only one ajax call fired on bkk_show.php.

Comment: @Hmmm i've to to give e.preventdefault() but it just work once. when i reload it again and again. it will be multiple again

Comment: @JackHenaldy ... Sorry I didn't get you, what do you mean by when you reload it again and again, it will be multiple again?

Comment: i edit my code with giving the code you give to me. and it work just only once.
when i reload it or i try to change the value of where clause it will change to multiple again

Comment: hmm... i got that already..thx.
i just need to didnt bring data: data, into my display function